# What is this address I received from wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, packet

[image: the packets]

______source____________destination___

`41:9c:7f:78:b1:0c |     08:00:d0:58:59:4c`

I am trying to identify those addresses, the source and the destination, I thought it was IPv6 but then I realized it's too short to be IPv6, I don't know if this is the right forum for this. So if it's not, mind redirecting me to one?

Answer (score 4):

They are [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_access_control) addresses. These are [Layer 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) addresses while IP is [Layer 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). It shows MAC because IP is not known/used in this message.

Comment: Might be worth noting that this could also be derived from the Info field in the screenshot (Ethernet = Layer 2)

Comment: @Nomad Meeeh, I don't think the info is always Ethernet when MACs are used, but I am not sure. I don't use Wireshark as much. Still, I think i saw ARP there and ARP certainly uses MACs.

Answer (score 2):

They are MAC addresses, also known as Ethernet addresses.

They identify the Ethernet network interface card (NIC) and, as such, belong to Layer 2, unlike IPv4/6 addresses which belong to Layer 3.

As they are tied to the physical card, they can only be used to derive the card manufacturer, nothing else.

They are not grouped by subnets or by ISP and, as a result, cannot be used to geolocate a device.

Comment: The _default_ MAC address depends on the manufacturer, but it usually can be and often is changed by the OS/stack. If the manufacturer id (left 3 octets less two bits) is known, Wireshark displays that in its decode, and did not do so here.